# m3u8x, how to run on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, download, m3u8

I use m3u8x for downloading m3u8-videos as *.ts-file. It good working on Windows 7, but when I try to get video info on Window 10, I have this error (see screenshot):

unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19045 x86_x64)

How to fix it?

Screenshot:
[image]

I try to add Chrome.exe to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER/..." via regedit, but it didn't help.
Also I did all from the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLm8A-ZQTDk but it didn't help.

I expect that m3u8x will be work on Windows 10 as good as on Windows 7.